# How to login user after creating it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have the following method to create a new user in Azure Active Directory using the Graph API:

```
public static async Task AddUserAsync(User user)
{
    Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.ActiveDirectoryClient adClient = 
        GetActiveDirectoryClient();

    await adClient.Users.AddUserAsync(user);
}
```

After the user is created using this method, I need to automatically log the user in.

I'm looking for something like the [SignInManager.SignInAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt173757(v=vs.108).aspx) or [SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt173779(v=vs.108).aspx) methods.

Comment: What does "logged-in" mean to you?  Your `GetActiveDirectoryClient` is already specifying some sort of credentials that will be used to access the Graph API.

Comment: I'm looking for something like the SignInManager.SignInAsync/PasswordSignInAsync method, but for signing users to AAD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to @David answer, when redirecting to Azure AD after creating the user you can specify `login_hint=user@domain.com`. This auto-fills the username in the login page.

Answer (score 2):

If you want them "really" logged in with AAD, you'll need to log the current user out and send them back to the login page so that they get sent through the Microsoft login process.

If you don't want to do this, you could probably create a user object manually that you could pass to `SignInManager.SignInAsync`.